# Wildfly 8 - passing exceptions from server to client

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly-8

please help to understand following issue:
After moving from JBoss to Wildfly 8, if some runtime exception is thrown in the bean, I excpect to receive this exception at client side, but instead I receive IO exception :

Client side:

```
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.io.IOException: Channel Channel ID ddd7dcd1 (outbound) of Remoting connection 12c97f7d to localhost/127.0.0.1:80 has been closed
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:236)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:181)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:144)
```

and in the server side I see this one:

```
14:26:00,167 ERROR [ejb3] JBAS014250: Could not write method invocation failure for method public abstract void com.allot.nms.catalog.mobile.ejb.MobileControllerInternal.replaceCatalogEntries(java.util.Collection) throws com.allot.nms.catalog.exception.CatalogException on bean named MobileControllerBean for appname NMS modulename catalog distinctname  due to: java.io.IOException: JBAS014560: Could not open message outputstream for writing to Channel
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.AbstractMessageHandler.writeException(AbstractMessageHandler.java:102)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.access$400(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:70)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler$1.run(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:213)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
       at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1302)
       at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:312)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.ChannelAssociation.acquireChannelMessageOutputStream(ChannelAssociation.java:66)

at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.AbstractMessageHandler.writeException(AbstractMessageHandler.java:100)
```

It seems that there is some problem to handle the originally thrown exception. 
Same code worked with JBoss. 
Any ideas how to fix it and make the exception propagate to client?
Thanks a lot.